# Poco HTTPSClientSession with google drive api

Tags: c++, c++11, google-drive-api, poco, poco-libraries

For my desktop app to access my google drive, I'm using [Poco](http://pocoproject.org) for authentication and queries. When requesting for access token, I'm facing problems with `Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession`. My code is given below.

```
namespace net = Poco::Net;
net::Context::Ptr ctx =
    new net::Context(net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", net::Context::VerificationMode::VERIFY_NONE);
net::HTTPSClientSession client("accounts.google.com", net::HTTPSClientSession::HTTPS_PORT, ctx);

net::HTTPRequest req(net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/o/oauth2/token", net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
net::HTMLForm    form;
form.add("code", accessCode);
form.add("client_secret", client_secret);
form.add("client_id", client_id);
form.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
form.add("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);
form.prepareSubmit(req);

// req.setChunkedTransferEncoding(true);

form.write(std::cout);
std::cout << std::endl;
client.sendRequest(req);

req.write(std::cout);
std::cout << "Method: " << req.getMethod() << std::endl;
net::HTTPResponse resp;
auto&&            is = client.receiveResponse(resp);
std::copy(
    std::istream_iterator<char>(is), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

I'm getting Timeout exception with the above code. If I turn on chunked transfer encoding, I'm getting error from google

> "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"

There's something incorrect with transfer encoding in my code which I could not figure out. What am I missing ?

Edit: The same request in Postman works fine (with or without chunked transfer-encoding).

Thanks,
Surya

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I'm not writing the form data into body of the request which is giving problems. Changed the code like this

```
auto&& strm = client.sendRequest(req);
form.write(strm);
```

Now it works.